# Extend model with a module inside a folder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module

All of my modules which extend my models live inside the "app/lib" directory but it's getting cluttered so I want to start grouping them in subfolders. How do I add a folder to the path when extending a module?

My current user model:

```
class User
  extend Match
  extend UserAnalytics
  extend Gaming

  ...
```

I'd like to group these modules in a subfolder "app/lib/user" instead, but how would I specify the new path to the modules?

Answer (score 1):

```
require "app/lib/user/Match"
...
class Anything
    extend Match
```

Should do the trick.